# can you please tell me whats wrong with this

Tags: c

need help please need help please
my code compiles fine but when i run it gives a seg fault and i have no idea why. i have gone over the code so many times but still no clue where the problem is. need help please.

```
void insertionSort(listNode ** listPtr, listNodeCompareFcn compare)
{

  listNode * sorted = *listPtr; 
  listNode * swapper; 
  listNode * prev; 
  int swapped; 

  while(sorted != NULL)
  {

    swapper = sorted -> next;
    prev = findprev(*listPtr, swapper);
    swapped = 0; 

    while(swapper != NULL && prev != NULL && swapper != *listPtr && compare(swapper,prev))

    { 
        swapNodes(*listPtr, prev, swapper); 
        prev = findprev(*listPtr, swapper); 
        swapped = 1;
    }

         if (!swapped) sorted = sorted -> next;

  }

}


static listNode * findprev(listNode * head, listNode * ptr){

    listNode * current = head;

    while (current -> next != NULL){
        if ((current -> next) == ptr) return current;
        current = current -> next;
   }    

  return NULL; 

} 

void swapNodes(listNode * head, listNode * l1, listNode * l2){

  listNode * prev = findprev(head, l1);
  prev -> next = l2;
  l1 -> next = l2 -> next;
  l2 -> next = l1; 

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [FAQ] soon. Please also learn how to write an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)); it helps people to help you. Your code above is not an SSCCE; we don't have the structure definition, nor a main program. Can you print your unsorted data? Cosmetically, when you write C, the `.` and `->` operators are never written with spaces around them; they bind very tightly. (For presenting code on SO, do not use tabs; do indent by 4 spaces per level; when copying code, use the **`{}`** button above the edit box to indent code.)

Comment: I've done enough work on an SSCCE to know that a major part of your problem is that you are not being careful enough with the head of your list.  If you swap the head node and the next node, you need to update the head node pointer, as otherwise you lose the front of the list.  I'm tolerably certain that's only a component of the trouble.  Given a valid list, the `findprev()` function works fine.  Neither `swapNodes()` nor `insertionSort()` can be given a clean bill of health, I think.  For instance, if `findprev()` returns NULL, `swapNodes()` happily dereferences the NULL pointer; crash!

Answer (score 2):

I commented:

> I've done enough work on an SSCCE to know that a major part of your problem is that you are not being careful enough with the head of your list. If you swap the head node and the next node, you need to update the head node pointer, as otherwise you lose the front of the list. I'm tolerably certain that's only a component of the trouble [*it was in fact the whole trouble*]. Given a valid list, the `findprev()` function works fine. Neither `swapNodes()` nor `insertionSort()` can be given a clean bill of health (*yet!*), I think. For instance, if `findprev()` returns NULL, `swapNodes()` happily dereferences the NULL pointer; crash!

Here is an SSCCE version of your code, updated with back-channel information about the fix to `swapNodes()` identified in the comment above. The `compare()` function turns out to be a C++ style comparator rather than a C style comparator; that is, it returns true if node 1 comes before node 2 and false otherwise (whereas a C style comparator returns -1, 0, +1 — or, strictly, negative, zero, positive — for less than, equal to, greater than).  With just the fix to `swapNodes()` — interface and code change — and the correct comparator semantics, the list is sorted correctly.  Hardly an exhaustive test, but a good start.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct listNode listNode;
struct listNode
{
    int datum;
    listNode *next;
};

typedef int (*listNodeCompareFcn)(const listNode *n1, const listNode *n2);
//static void swapNodes(listNode *head, listNode *l1, listNode *l2);
static void swapNodes(listNode **head, listNode *l1, listNode *l2);
static listNode *findprev(listNode *head, listNode *ptr);

static int node_compare(const listNode *n1, const listNode *n2)     // SSCCE
{
    assert(n1 != 0 && n2 != 0);
    printf("Compare: %2d and %2d\n", n1->datum, n2->datum);
    if (n1->datum < n2->datum)
        return 1;
//    if (n1->datum < n2->datum)
//        return -1;
//    else if (n1->datum > n2->datum)
//        return +1;
    else
        return 0;
}

static void insertionSort(listNode **listPtr, listNodeCompareFcn compare)
{
    listNode *sorted = *listPtr;

    while (sorted != NULL)
    {
        listNode *swapper = sorted->next;
        listNode *prev = findprev(*listPtr, swapper);
        int swapped = 0;

        while (swapper != NULL && prev != NULL && swapper != *listPtr && compare(swapper, prev))
        {
            //swapNodes(*listPtr, prev, swapper);
            swapNodes(listPtr, prev, swapper);
            prev = findprev(*listPtr, swapper);
            swapped = 1;
        }

        if (!swapped)
            sorted = sorted->next;
    }
}

static listNode *findprev(listNode *head, listNode *ptr)
{
    listNode *current = head;
    assert(current != 0);

    while (current->next != NULL)
    {
        if (current->next == ptr)
            return current;
        current = current->next;
    }

    return NULL;
}

// Update via email
void swapNodes(listNode **listPtr, listNode *l1, listNode *l2)
{
    listNode *prev = findprev(*listPtr, l1);
    if (prev == NULL)
    {
        l1->next = l2->next;
        *listPtr = l2;
        l2->next = l1;
    }
    else
    {
        prev->next = l2;
        l1->next = l2->next;
        l2->next = l1; 
    }
}

/*
static void swapNodes(listNode *head, listNode *l1, listNode *l2)
{
    listNode *prev = findprev(head, l1);
    prev->next = l2;
    l1->next = l2->next;
    l2->next = l1;
}
*/

static listNode *node_insert(listNode *head, int datum)     // SSCCE
{
    listNode *node = malloc(sizeof(*node));
    node->datum = datum;
    node->next = head;
    return node;
}

static void print_list(const char *tag, const listNode *list)       // SSCCE
{
    printf("%-8s", tag);
    while (list != 0)
    {
        printf(" -> %2d", list->datum);
        list = list->next;
    }
    putchar('\n');
}

int main(void)      // SSCCE
{
    static const int unsorted[] = { 29, 3, 14, 2, 91, 87, 13, 29, 1 };
    enum { NUM_VALUES = sizeof(unsorted) / sizeof(unsorted[0]) };
    listNode *head = 0;

    print_list("Empty:", head);
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_VALUES; i++)
    {
        head = node_insert(head, unsorted[i]);
        print_list("Added:", head);
    }

    for (listNode *curr = head; curr != 0; curr = curr->next)
    {
        listNode *prev = findprev(head, curr);
        if (prev == 0)
            printf("%2d - no prior node\n", curr->datum);
        else
            printf("%2d - prior node %2d\n", curr->datum, prev->datum);
    }

    print_list("Before:", head);
    insertionSort(&head, node_compare);
    print_list("After:", head);

    return 0;
}
```

Output (including diagnostics) from the SSCCE:

```
Empty:  
Added:   -> 29
Added:   ->  3 -> 29
Added:   -> 14 ->  3 -> 29
Added:   ->  2 -> 14 ->  3 -> 29
Added:   -> 91 ->  2 -> 14 ->  3 -> 29
Added:   -> 87 -> 91 ->  2 -> 14 ->  3 -> 29
Added:   -> 13 -> 87 -> 91 ->  2 -> 14 ->  3 -> 29
Added:   -> 29 -> 13 -> 87 -> 91 ->  2 -> 14 ->  3 -> 29
Added:   ->  1 -> 29 -> 13 -> 87 -> 91 ->  2 -> 14 ->  3 -> 29
 1 - no prior node
29 - prior node  1
13 - prior node 29
87 - prior node 13
91 - prior node 87
 2 - prior node 91
14 - prior node  2
 3 - prior node 14
29 - prior node  3
Before:  ->  1 -> 29 -> 13 -> 87 -> 91 ->  2 -> 14 ->  3 -> 29
Compare: 29 and  1
Compare: 13 and 29
Compare: 13 and  1
Compare: 87 and 29
Compare: 91 and 87
Compare:  2 and 91
Compare:  2 and 87
Compare:  2 and 29
Compare:  2 and 13
Compare:  2 and  1
Compare: 14 and 91
Compare: 14 and 87
Compare: 14 and 29
Compare: 14 and 13
Compare:  3 and 91
Compare:  3 and 87
Compare:  3 and 29
Compare:  3 and 14
Compare:  3 and 13
Compare:  3 and  2
Compare: 29 and 91
Compare: 29 and 87
Compare: 29 and 29
After:   ->  1 ->  2 ->  3 -> 13 -> 14 -> 29 -> 29 -> 87 -> 91
```